# Python - remove last character when writing to a file

Tags: python

I'm writing a dict variable into a text file

```
for key, value in dict.items():
   input_file.write("%s:%s\n" % (key, value))
```

How can I delete the last \n from the file that is generated?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) would take care,

```
input_file.write(
    "\n".join("%s:%s" % (key, value) for key, value in dict.items())
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest inserting the `\n` *before* the new line, except the first one:

```
prefix = ''
for key, value in dict.items():
    input_file.write(f'{prefix}{key}:{value}')  # also: modern formatting
    prefix = '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
data = {'A':12,'B':34}
for idx,key in enumerate(data.keys()):
   new_line = '' if idx == len(data) -1 else '\n'
   input_file.write("{}:{}{}".format(key, data[key],new_line))
```

Answer (score 0):

One can [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to file. So one can separate k, v pairs with newline and set end to empty string:

```
print(*(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in d.items()), sep='\n', end='', file=input_file)
```